# load html, css and js files from a zip file into the webView

Tags: swift, webkit

I have an endpoint that send me a zip file with `html` , `js` and `css` files (a local web project). My question is there a solution to load the web project in a `webkitview` without changing the relative paths in the html files and if not is there an other solution ? I thought about loading the `html` file as string and then inject the `css` and `js` to the `webkit` but I will not access to the images because they have their relative paths in `html` page. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

For this type of case, you can use Cross-Platform Application Development. ie. Cordova, which will provide support directly to add and render your assets as native application.

or you can load html file directly to web view:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "home", withExtension: "html") {
            webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
```

Comment: thank you Bhavik Modi for your reply, but the problem is that the project has already began and there is no a way to restart the project with cross-plateforme development.

Comment: yeah I already try this solution, it works perfectly if you have all the files in a local directory in the project but for me I get the files from an endpoint.

Comment: So, is it like everytime you call service which provides you updated html and other assets? and you wants to present those files in web view ?

Comment: Yeah thats right, every time I passe a different id to the service it will provide me with different content of html, css, js and jpg files and I want to load these files in the webView I succeeded to load a html page as string and inject the css and js but the images and the other html files are provided with relative paths in the html code so they will not be shown

Comment: Can you please share how the relative path is assigned?

Comment: for images : src="./assets/empty.png" and for html files href="./example.html">